# Building FFTW library in "Release Mode"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-7-x64, fftw

I am trying to use the [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) library in visual studios 2013 with windows 7/8.1 operating system (my work computer's operating sysyem/and my personal computer's operating system) and have followed the instructions depicted [here](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html) to build the libraries using Visual Studio's lib.exe tool. So far I have been experimenting fine with library when I run my program in DEBUG mode, but when I try to run my program in RELEASE mode I get LNK2001 errors for all the fftw functions I call.

```
1>runexample.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_free
1>runexample.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_execute
1>runexample.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_cleanup
1>runexample.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_plan_dft_2d
1>runexample.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_alloc_complex
1>runexample.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_destroy_plan
```

I have searched online for a solution to this problem and consulted FFTW [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/) but I have not found any answers. Is there way to build  or link against "release" libraries for fftw or am doing something else wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Those are import libraries (indicated by the `__imp_` prefix).  There is no such thing as a "debug" import library or "release" import library.  An import library simply contains stubs to the functions that exist in a DLL or other executable.  So maybe the issue is that you did not add the import library to your project for `Release` mode?

Comment: Thanks, Original I did not specify them in the config manager, and I guess it found them ok when building in Debug. But then when I added the libraries it worked fine for when I want to build in release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFTW does not distinguish between "release" and "debug" import libraries. There is one set of libraries shipped with FFTW that can be used for both "release" and "debug" builds.

A common cause of a library linking issue between "debug" and "release" mode is that the configuration was only applied to the "debug" mode and not also to the "release" mode. In "debug" mode compilers are typically more lax and bugs can slip through that won't in "release" mode.